# 'cat /proc/swaps' returns nothing

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, swap

**Please do not waste anymore of your time on this question...I ended up deleting the whole VM and creating another. The time it took me to do this is less than the time it would take to fix the issue. I have couple of SSDs in RAID mode.**

**Thank you for all those who tried to troubleshoot the issue!**

I am having this problem with ubnuntu not showing active swap spaces when I run the command `cat /proc/swaps`. Here is a list of commands I ran. I even added a new swap space (file: /swapfile1) just to make sure that at least one swap space, but still I get nothing.

```
hebbo@ubuntu-12-lts:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for hebbo: 

Disk /dev/sda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders, total 52428800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e3a7a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *    46569472    52426751     2928640   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2            2046    46567423    23282689    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            2048    46567423    23282688   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
hebbo@ubuntu-12-lts:~$ sudo su

root@ubuntu-12-lts:/home/hebbo# cat /proc/swaps 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
root@ubuntu-12-lts:/home/hebbo# dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288
524288+0 records in
524288+0 records out
536870912 bytes (537 MB) copied, 1.18755 s, 452 MB/s
root@ubuntu-12-lts:/home/hebbo# mkswap /swapfile1
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 524284 KiB
no label, UUID=cb846612-5f27-428f-9f83-bbe24b410a78
root@ubuntu-12-lts:/home/hebbo# chown root:root /swapfile1
root@ubuntu-12-lts:/home/hebbo# chmod 0600 /swapfile1
root@ubuntu-12-lts:/home/hebbo# swapon /swapfile1


root@ubuntu-12-lts:/home/hebbo# cat /proc/swaps 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
root@ubuntu-12-lts:/home/hebbo#
```

Any idea how to fix this?

This is ubuntu 12.04 LTS running kernel 3.9.0 in a vmware VM.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Is there a reason you've got both a swap partition (`/dev/sda`) and a swap file (`/swapfile1`)? I don't think it's likely the cause of your `/proc/swaps` issue, but perhaps there's something larger going on you didn't mention?

Comment: No, there is no reason for that. I added the swapfile /swapfile1 for verification purposes. But I should have the swap partition before I added the swap file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the whole VM and creating another. The time it took me to do this is less than the time it would take to fix the issue. I have couple of SSDs in RAID mode. And I already had all the downloads on the same host machine. All in all ~7 minutes.

Thanks for all those who helped troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To activate /swapfile1 after Linux system reboot, add entry to /etc/fstab file. Open this file using a text editor such as vi:

```
# vi /etc/fstab
```

Add the following line:

```
/swapfile1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Save and close the file. Next time Linux comes up after reboot, it enables the new swap file for you automatically.

Have a look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/) for more info.

Comment: This is just to make the change permanent. If you just need the swap file until the next reboot what I did should be fine (I tried it before). My issue is not just related to the file. My other swap partition should appear too.

Comment: Enable the new swap partition with this command.
`sudo swapon --all` then check the `cat /proc/swaps` entry.

Comment: Thank you for your help! as my update to the question, I ended up deleting the whole VM and creating another.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and it works on my box.

`Linux fileserver 3.8.0-32-generic #47~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 16:19:35 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
ortang@fileserver:~$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2                               partition       4194300 0       -1
ortang@fileserver:~$ sudo su
root@fileserver:/home/ortang# dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=512
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
536870912 bytes (537 MB) copied, 0.695721 s, 772 MB/s
root@fileserver:/home/ortang# chmod 600 /swapfile
root@fileserver:/home/ortang# mkswap /swapfile
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 524284 KiB
no label, UUID=63cdcf3d-ba03-42ce-b598-15b6aa3ca67d
root@fileserver:/home/ortang# swapon /swapfile
root@fileserver:/home/ortang# cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2                               partition       4194300 0       -1
/swapfile                               file            524284  0       -2
```

One thing i can imagine why it is working on my box, is that i already have a working swap partition, and it seems you don't.

It could also be caused by the kernel you use, 3.9.0 is not the regular 12.04.3 LTS kernel? Have you built the kernel yourself?

Whats the output of

```
grep CONFIG_SWAP /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

or

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_SWAP
```

is swap enabled in your kernel?

Comment: Thank you for your help! as my update to the question, I ended up deleting the whole VM and creating another.